# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' in gitlab pipeline for Flask application run

Tags: flask, gitlab

Trying to build and deploy and run a flask app from gitlab.  Here is the .gitlab-ci.yaml file.  I am trying to resolve an error I am seeing in Gitlab where it does not recognize flask

```
image: python:3.11

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - source venv/Scripts/activate  # Activate the virtual environment
    - python app.py
```

Attached are the app.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
tasks = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', tasks=tasks)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    task = request.form.get('task')
    tasks.append(task)
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/delete/<int:task_id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete(task_id):
    tasks.pop(task_id)
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I then have the requirements.txt

```
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
Werkzeug==3.0.1
```

In the templates directory, I have an index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask To-Do List</h1>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Enter task">
        <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <li>
                {{ task }}
                <form action="/delete/{{ loop.index0 }}" method="post" style="display:inline;">
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error in gitlab.How can I resolve?

[image]

Comment: In step `build`, you install package direct to os but in step `deploy` you use virtual environment that made not found package. Try to remove `source venv/Scripts/activate` and only run `python app.py`